# Browser version detection without using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Identifying the version of a browser using JavaScript is quite straight forward.

Is there any way to identify the browser version without using JavaScript libraries??

I just felt that there should be some way to identify the browser version without using any external libraries. I'm just very much curious to know if there is any way to do so..

Comment: Is there a reason you need to know what version of a browser someone is using?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with what you would like to do with this.  There are ways of targeting CSS at certain browsers.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me.  What would you do with a browser version without javascript.  Acting on a browser version (to do something based on which browser version is way) requires logic which requires a programming language of some kind.  IE has conditional comments.  Is that what you want?

Comment: What is the purpose of identifying the browser, styling?

Comment: It's "JavaScript", not "Java script", "javascript", or "java script", all of which you had in your question. (I think that's a record, literally every place you mentioned it you wrote it slightly differently...) :-)

Comment: @zzzzBov The OP must have a reason. Otherwise, he wouldn't be asking the question... `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - As the question is fairly obtuse, the reason behind the question is relevant to understanding what type of answer would be appropriate.  Way too many questions on SO ask for a particular type of solution without stating the problem when stating the problem could get a much, much better answer than they even know to ask for.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Oh if only that were always true... ;-) (May well be true *here*.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Its a typo.. Sorry about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A bad reason is a reason too... `:)`

Comment: @zzzzBov : Styling is one issue why I want to identify the browser type.

Comment: @all : As I mentioned in my question I know how to find out the browser version using javascript. I just felt that there should be some way to identify the browser version without using any external libraries. I'm just very much curious to know if there is any way to do so.. Right now I'm sing PHP but I even want to know the solution using Java..

Comment: @Neal, I see practically no reason to know the browser or version for styling. The only one that requires special care is IE, and you can use conditional comments to fix its many many issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to do this client-side, then you certainly can use javascript.  However this is also trivial with most server-side languages.  All you need is access to the `User Agent` HTTP header.

Comment: So according to your answer its almost compulsory to use javascript to identify browser version and type on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Most libraries just parse the user-agent string, which is sent to the server as an HTTP header, so any server side process could do it.

The usual warnings about browser sniffing being unreliable, hard to maintain, and usually the wrong solution to any given problem apply.

Answer (score 1):

The http request contains the header `User-Agent`

Answer (score 0):

You can include conditional comments in your HTML to select versions of IE, but as far as I know, it doesn't work for other browsers. http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of detection on the server side? For [PHP there is this](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/).